# No operations defined in spec!! and 404 error in postman. The spring boot don't show any error from my code. yet i can't establish the connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, postman, microservices

This is a simple code that i got  from youtube for practice. well i did the code correcly but i cant get the explicit mapping correclty, that what the 404 error in the postman says.
I don't know if its my Spring boot app problem or the code error. please have a look at this  , Since spring boot is not giving a proper answer.

//CONTROLLER

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class RestuController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestuService restuService;
    
    /////////////////////////////////////POST MAPPING//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    @PostMapping("/POST/save")
     Restaurant addRestaurant(@RequestBody Restaurant restaurant) {
        
        return restuService.saveRestu(restaurant);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/POST/saves")
    List<Restaurant> addRestaurants(@RequestBody List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
        
        return  restuService.saveRestaurants(restaurants);
        
    }
@GetMapping("/GET/resturants")
     List<Restaurant> findAllRestaurants(){
        log.debug("reached /GET/resturants");
        return restuService.getRestaurants();
        }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/GET/{id}")
     Restaurant findRestaurantById(@PathVariable int id) {
        log.debug("reached /GET/{id} :" + id);
        return restuService.getRestaurantById(id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/GET/{name}")
    Restaurant findRestaurantByName(@PathVariable  String name) {
        log.debug("reached /GET/{name}:" + name);
        return restuService.getRestaurantByname(name);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/GET/{dist}")
   List<Restaurant> findRestaurantByDist(@PathVariable int distance) {  
        log.debug("reached /GET/{dist} :" + distance);
        return restuService.getRestaurantbyDist(distance);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/GET/{loc}")
    List<Restaurant> findRestaurantByLocation(@PathVariable String location) {
        log.debug("reached /GET/{loc} : " + location);
        return restuService.getRestaurantbyLocation(location);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/GET/{cuisine}")
      List<Restaurant> findRestaurantByCuisine(@PathVariable String cuisine) {
        log.debug("reached /GET/{cuisine} : " + cuisine);
        return restuService.getRestaurantbyCuisine(cuisine);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/GET/{budget}")
     
    List<Restaurant> findRestaurantByBudget(@PathVariable int budget) {
        log.debug("reached /GET/{Budget} : " + budget);
        return restuService.getRestaurantbyBudget(budget);
}
    
    
    

}
```

//SERVICE

```
package SERVICE;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import ENTITY.Restaurant;
import REPOSITORY.RestuRepository;

@Service
public class RestuService {
    
    @Autowired
     RestuRepository restuRepository;
    
    ///////////////////postmethods//////////////////////////////////////
    
    
    
    public  Restaurant saveRestu(Restaurant restaurant) {
          return restuRepository.save(restaurant);
           
    }
    
    public List<Restaurant> saveRestaurants(List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
        return restuRepository.saveAll(restaurants);
    }
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////GET METHODS//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    public List<Restaurant> getRestaurants(){
        return restuRepository.findAll();
    }
    

    public Restaurant getRestaurantById(int id){
        return restuRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
    public Restaurant getRestaurantByname(String name){
        return restuRepository.findByName(name);
    }
    

    public List<Restaurant> getRestaurantbyDist(int distance){
        return restuRepository.findByDist(distance);
    }
    

    public List<Restaurant> getRestaurantbyLocation(String  location){
        return restuRepository.findByLocation(location);
    }
    

    public List<Restaurant> getRestaurantbyCuisine(String  cuisine){
        return restuRepository.findBycuisine(cuisine);
    }
    
    public List<Restaurant> getRestaurantbyBudget(int  budget){
        return restuRepository.findBybudget(budget);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    

}
```

//REPOSITORY

```
package REPOSITORY;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ENTITY.Restaurant;

@Repository
public interface RestuRepository extends JpaRepository<Restaurant, Integer> {

    Restaurant findByName(String name);

    List<Restaurant> findByDist(int distance);

    List<Restaurant> findByLocation(String location);

    List<Restaurant> findBycuisine(String cuisine);

    List<Restaurant> findBybudget(int budget);
    

}
```

//ENTITY OR MODEL CLASS

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity


@Table(name = "restaurant_tbl")
public class Restaurant {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String cuisine;
    private String location;
    private int distance;
    private int budget;

}
```

//APPLICATION.PROPERTIES

```
server.port = 6282

spring.datasource.dbcp2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurants
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = ****
spring.jpa.show-sql =true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
```

//POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sangamam</groupId>
    <artifactId>RESTAURANT-SERVICE</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RESTAURANT-SERVICE</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What url are you requesting?

Comment: it's related to that you are requesting the url that not found and please don't define your url like `/POST/save` . for best practices, check this page -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design

Comment: okey........ problem solved. Its because i didn't provide the package name correctly. look at the package name . i just gave it as controller, service, repository. But it should be like  com.example.name.package